# Open filename with embedded spaces with Roo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, filenames

Ruby 2.0.0, Rails 4.0.3, Windows 8.1 Update, Roo 1.13.2

I am trying to open an Excel spreadsheet with embedded spaces using Roo.  So far, I am unable to do that.  I don't really know if this problem is restricted to Roo.  If I rename it to eliminate the spaces, I have no problem with it.  I tried encoding it, but then it simply said the file doesn't exist.  Can I open the file while it contains spaces?

Code sample:

```
  exceptions = [URI::InvalidURIError, IOError]
  puts "f is #{f}"
  puts "f exist? #{File.exist?(f)}"
  begin
    xls = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(f)
  rescue *exceptions => e
    puts e.message
  end

  encoded_f = URI.encode(f).to_s
  puts "encoded_f is #{encoded_f}"
  puts "encoded_f exist? #{File.exist?(encoded_f)}"
  begin
    xls = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(encoded_f)
  rescue *exceptions => e
    puts e.message
  end

  gsub_f = f.gsub(" ", "") # Rename file without spaces
  File.rename(f, gsub_f)
  puts "gsub_f is #{gsub_f}"
  puts "gsub_f exist? #{File.exist?(gsub_f)}"
  begin
    xls = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(gsub_f)
  rescue *exceptions => e
    puts e.message
  end
```

Output sample:

```
f is Whitt Report 2014-07-28-0803.xls
f exist? true
bad URI(is not URI?): Whitt Report 2014-07-28-0803.xls

encoded_f is Whitt%20Report%202014-07-28-0803.xls
encoded_f exist? false
file Whitt%20Report%202014-07-28-0803.xls does not exist

gsub_f is WhittReport2014-07-28-0803.xls
gsub_f exist? true
```

No message is given in the end because the file opens successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by the way in which the URI module is called in the `Roo::Spreadsheet#open` method.

I posted a fix to this problem which has now been merged. If you update your Roo gem you should no longer have this issue.

Comment: I thought this was fixed, but further testing says I was mistaken.  I'd like to verify that I have the update.  Looking at the repository, I don't see what I should check.  Can you point me in that direction?  Thanks.

Comment: I guess I'll have to leave this open until I get a resolution.